# Add Class before slide open and remove class after slide close using slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using jQuery to slide a menu open and closed when a link is clicked which is working great. However, I'm trying to add a class when the link is clicked before the menu slides open then remove the same class after the menu slides back closed.

So: click > addClass > slide menu open > click again > slide menu closed > removeClass

```
    $("#categoryNav").hide();
    $('#showHideLink').click(function(){
        $("#categoryNav").slideToggle(function() { 
            $('#showHideLink').toggleClass("catMenuOpen");
            $('#mainNav').toggleClass("catMenuOpen");
        });
    });
```

I've tried adding `$('#mainNav'.addClass('catMenuOpen');` before the `slideToggle` function instead of using the `toggleClass` which gives me the correct effect on the first click, but I can't figure out how to remove the class after the nav has closed again.

Cheers

**EDIT:**
Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="mainNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a id="showHideLink">Show Hide</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="categoryNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CatMenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `catMenuOpen` class should be applied to what elements? Both `showHideLink` and `mainNav`?

Comment: Yes, both. But `catMenuOpen` can be added/removed from `showHideLink` at any time durring the process. I'm mainly concerned about when `catMenuOpen` is applied to `mainNav`.

Comment: @Bryan can you provide your html code here, then we will give accurate answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it in the order you asked:

```
$('#showHideLink').click(function(){

    if (!$("#categoryNav").is(":visible"))
        $('#showHideLink, #mainNav').addClass("catMenuOpen");

    $("#categoryNav").slideToggle(function() { 
        if (!$("#categoryNav").is(":visible"))
            $('#showHideLink, #mainNav').removeClass("catMenuOpen");
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Check it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/b5sFP/)

Comment: Thank you! Clean and simple and works like a charm. :) I was unaware of the `:visible` selector, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('#showHideLink').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("catMenuOpen"){
       $(this).removeClass("catMenuOpen");
    }else
       $(this).addClass("catMenuOpen");
    $("#categoryNav").slideToggle(function() { 
        $('#showHideLink').toggleClass("catMenuOpen");
        $('#mainNav').toggleClass("catMenuOpen");
    });
```

I'm not entirely sure the above code will work 100%, because I don't have a chance to actually test it, but the idea is that if the element has the "open" class then you want to remove it (since you've clicked again and are closing the div). If you click and the element doesn't have the "open" class then you want to add it to the div.

Answer (score 1):

try creating a string array having class names and then on every click, toggle b/w the array values..

```
<script>
var i=0;
var classes = new Array("catMenuClose","catMenuOpen");
$("#categoryNav").hide();
$('#showHideLink').click(function(){
    i=i*(-1)+1;
    $("#categoryNav").slideToggle(function() { 
        $('#showHideLink').toggleClass(classes[i]);
        $('#mainNav').toggleClass(classes[i]);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one, hope this will help

```
$('#showHideLink').click(function(){

    $("#categoryNav").slideToggle(function() { 
        var property = $('#categoryNav').css('display');
        if(property == 'block')
        $('#showHideLink, #mainNav').addClass("catMenuOpen");
        else
        $('#showHideLink, #mainNav').removeClass("catMenuOpen");
    });
});
```

this is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eh6jv/1/

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this while looking for something else. Here is a working code for this.

/*===================SCRIPT STARTS HERE ====================*/

```
(function($){    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#open_sidebar').click(function() {       
           if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
             $("#open_sidebar").toggleClass("open").removeClass('closed');
             $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Close Window' ? 'Open Window' : 'Close Window'); 
           } else {                
             $("#open_sidebar").toggleClass("closed").removeClass('open');
             $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Open Window' ? 'Close Window' : 'Open Window');    
           }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

/*===================SCRIPT ENDS HERE ====================*/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="open_sidebar">Open Window</div>
```

Here is what will happen on click:

```
<div id="open_sidebar" class="open">Close Window</div>
```

And on 2nd click:

```
<div id="open_sidebar" class="closed">Open Window</div>
```